# XHTML inline div inside anchor tag

Tags: html, xhtml, anchor, inline

I want to have an image roll-over link and use sprites. Is it ok to do put an inline div inside an anchor with no text?

```
<a href="link.html"><div style="display:inline;background:etc;"></div></a>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-a-anchor-ever-correct/1828032#1828032

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to the W3C a `div` may not live inside an `a` element, unless you're declaring the doctype as HTML5*. Also, why would you use a `div` and make it `display:inline` if a `span` does the same and is standards-compliant at the same time?

* http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Answer (score 2):

No, block level elements aren't allowed inside inline level elements, and will cause undefined behaviour. Use a `span` instead.